# Javascript creating new Date from UK Formated datetime in Chrome returns invalid date

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

I am attempting to debug an issue causing chrome to have issues.  It seems to occur when a UK formated datetime string is passed to the Date constructor.  My system is all en-us I just had to change my browser settings to en-uk for testing purposes, not sure if that matters.

I have simplified the problem down to the following

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    alert('hi')
    var inactiveDateValue = new Date("18/04/2013");
    alert(inactiveDateValue);
</script>
Testing some DateTime Functionality with JS.
</body>
</html>
```

I have set my language to English (UK) as my highest priority.

EDIT:
I need to be able to parse USA or UK datetime formats so the value may be 04/18/2013 OR 18/04/2013.

Comment: Do it locale agnostically; `inactiveDateValue = new Date(2013, 3 - 1, 18)` : (`-1` as the month is zero based, valid date constructor formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to parse string **DD/MM/YYYY** to JavaScript `Date`, you can do the following:

```
var parseUKDate = function (source, delimiter) {
   return new Date(source.split(delimiter).reverse().join(delimiter))
};

var activeDateValue = parseUKDate("18/04/2013", "/");
alert(activeDateValue);
```

Comment: It needs to be generic enough to accept UK or USA formats.  Since the same page is used by USA and UK clients.